# Appropriate Background Image Size

Tags: android

My app keeps crashing due to an "Out of memory" exception. I'm almost positive that it has something to do with all of my images used within the app. I threw them in my drawable folder in the beginning without ever considering their size. For example, I use a background .png image in all of my Fragments. It's size is 832x561. Is that too large for say a standard android phone like a nexus 5? Is there a reference chart for appropriate image size based on device? Thank you.

Comment: In general you should not put non-xml drawables to res/drawable, because drawables from this folder are treated without any scaling. This means on every device you are loading 832x561 image into memory. This is too much for low-end devices with small screens. Instead you should put respective size of your image into drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc.

Comment: Lets say that i'm going to use this app only on phones just as an example. What would the appropriate drawable folder name be and would i need to scale down my 832x561 image in an image editor  or just put it in the folder and Android automatically will do it?

Comment: Put it in `drawable-nodpi`